# Populate listview with data from firebase on androidstudio

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to insert data of my firebase databse on listview, but, I didn't succeed.
My firebase has a "main node" named "ocorrencias", inside have some information and I want to insert this data (information) in listview (image with data in firebase).
[Database firebase, with data to insert in listview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEatP.png)
Someone can help me?

Hugs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using FirebaseUI you can populate a RecyclerView as well as a ListView following this guides ([RecyclerView guide](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-recyclerview) and [ListView guide](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-listview)) but because you asked for a ListView I will explain just this case.

Before start coding you have to connect your project to Firebase. If you didn't yet, you can follow this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup). Now we can start retrieving real-time data from the Firebase database.

First you have to add the following line in the dependencies of the `app/build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:2.3.0'
```

Then, in your Activity, you have to find your ListView:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_id);
```

And get a reference to your database:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

So you have to create the Adapter that will pass the data to the ListView. The FirebaseUI has its own [version](https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseListAdapter.html) of adapter that you can use.

```
FirebaseListAdapter mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<YourDatabaseObject>(this, YourDatabaseObject.class, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, ref) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, YourDatabaseObject databaseField, int position) {
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(databaseField.getField1());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(databaseField.getField2());

    }
};
// Set the adapter of the ListView
listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

You can replace YourDatabaseObject with your class that represents the data from the Firebase database (in your case Ocurencias). If you didn't create it yet you can follow this [guide](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#creating-a-model-class).
If you want you can also replace the layout IDs because I used the default ones.

In this way the ListView should now display the data from your database and get automatically updated when new data is inserted into the database.

If you didn't already create the objects needed to display data you can follow the guides liked above or read the [official documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/README.md) of FirebaseUI.

Comment: Do you mean that pasting this code as it is in your application it doesn't work?

Comment: No pasting, but, I understand your code and my doubts are solved. Thanks for your answer.In your code, I can insert data, but to populate it's necessary "for". +1

Comment: Glad that you fixed your issue